# How do I negate a value in a SET clause for SQL Server Compact?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET [MyBoolColumn] = NOT [MyBoolColumn]
```

That doesn't work on SQL Server CE. Error is

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token in error = NOT]

So how do I get this to work?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev That question has nothing to do with mine. Mine is for UPDATEs. Anyways, someone posted a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyBoolColumn BIT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (MyBoolColumn)
VALUES (0), (1)

UPDATE @MyTable
SET MyBoolColumn = ~MyBoolColumn

SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```

results -

```
------------
1
0
```

Comment: Nice. The [reference is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174624%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).